# IIFE problem while creating a simple calculator

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JS and wanted to practice for Functions and IIFE , below is the code i have made , at first i just created addition function , then i created subtraction function. while running the script it only showing the output of subtraction , hence i used IIFE . but still i don't know what should i do which will run both the functions. Please Suggest .

```js
function showMessage() {
  console.log("A Simple Calculator")
}

showMessage();

(function addition(x, y) {
  return x + y;

})();

addition(10, 11);

(function subtraction(a, b) {
  return a - b;

})();

subtraction(25, 15);
```

Comment: Why are you using IIFE here?

Comment: Using IIFE's here is completely pointless.

Comment: Your functions don't output anything. If you run them in a REPL (read,eval,print,loop) like a browser's console, it will output the result of the last evaluated expression. If you remove the IIFE and do this: `console.log( addition(10,11) ); console.log( subtraction( 25, 15 ) );` you will see the output of both functions.

Comment: I get `ReferenceError: addition is not defined`. If your browser does not throw an exception for that code, it's broken.

Comment: He added the IIFE to try to get it to output, his original code did not have an IIFE, so would not have a scope issue. "while running the script it only showing the output of subtraction , hence i used IIFE" @m0meni 's answer is correct . Why does it have three downvotes?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use `console.log` to print the results of your computations. The reason why subtraction is being displayed is that it's the last value that's evaluated by whatever environment you're running your code in, and is printed by default.

Instead of using an IIFE use

```
console.log(addition(10, 11))
console.log(subtraction(25, 15))
```

to print the output of addition and subtraction.

Comment: Lol why was I *instantly* downvoted three times? This is the answer. His REPL is printing the last evaluated value.

Comment: I think people didn't read the full question and didn't realize his original code didn't have IIFE's so they think your code won't work because `addition` and `subtraction` are not in scope. I'm pretty sure the downvotes came before you edited in "Instead of using an IIFE use" too. This is the answer though and hopefully the downvoters see that and switch their votes.

Comment: @Paulpro well I appreciate you noticing at least haha

Comment: I'd like to see an explanation of what's wrong with the IIFE code and why it can't work. This answer seems incomplete.

Comment: ... particularly since OP calls this an "IIFE problem" and started his question by saying he wanted to practice using IIFEs.

Comment: @melpomene I'm pretty sure the OP doesn't really know what an IIFE is and just wants his code to output the result of both calls. He seems to incorrectly believe that IIFEs are a way to output something and that is the only reason he wants to use them. The fact that they cause a scope issue is about as relevant to his question as any other kind of error that could be caused by trying any random thing. Albeit the title isn't great given the OP's actual question.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not exactly sure what you are asking, but if you're going to use an IIFE, you need to make sure you pass in the required parameters needed to complete the function invocation.

Part of your code is

```
(function addition(x, y) {
return x + y;
})();
```

This portion of code will result in a return of NaN because, essentially, you're passing (undefined, undefined) by not providing any parameters. You need to pass in two parameters. Same goes for your subtraction IIFE.

Also worth noting, because you create the addition and subtraction function using an IIFE, you cannot use those functions on a global level because they are not within scope.

Comment: Running the IIFE that you created that has no parameters, returns NaN. Dealing with NaN and its coercions will prove problematic. *I'll edit my answer for a clearer meaning